# Editing Android phone contacts on the fly from a Windows PC

Tags: contacts, usb-debugging

Is there any way to edit contacts on my Android phone from a Windows PC and without internet connectivity? Perhaps by using USB debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your contacts are synced to some service like Google or your mobile carrier, you should be able to do that right through their website (or Gmail, if all of your contacts are synced with your Google account). Any changes you make in your account on a PC, including contacts, will automatically sync to your device.

Comment: syncing with google contacts, sometimes it makes my contacts messy and merges names with google email names;

Note : By the way this question is asked to get rid out of messy contacts while doing sync with server